# Adding values together based on their position in PHP

Tags: php, list, math

Each number has a corresponding value with it. There are many numbers which I can demonstate in a table here with their appropriate values:

```
[N] [V]      N=Number V=Value
2   19
4   19
6   19
8   21
10  21
12  22
14  23
16  23
18  23
20  33
22  37
24  42
26  45
28  48
30  50
32  55
34  61
36  66
38  72
40  78
42  155
44  179
46  202
48  233
50  360
```

There is a process that a user will go through where they go from Number x to Number y. The values inbetween those numbers need to get added together. So for example, let's say a user goes from 16 to 38:

```
[N] [V]      N=Number V=Value
2   19
4   19
6   19
8   21
10  21
12  22
14  23
[16][23]--
18  23   |
20  33   |
22  37   |
24  42   |
26  45   |
28  48   |---- All of these values get added together
30  50   |
32  55   |
34  61   |
36  66   |
[38][72]--
40  78
42  155
44  179
46  202
48  233
50  360
```

So the users total value would equal be:

```
 23 + 23 + 33 + 37 + 42 + 45 + 48 + 50 + 55 + 61 + 66 + 72
 Total Value = 555
```

The problem is, is that I have no idea how I to put this together in code. Like how to assign these values to their specific number and how to add those specific values together to get me a result. In PHP I simply do not know where to begin with this.

Also, the approximate values from the numbers can be represented by this equation:

```
 v = 11.218e^(0.057n)
```

I would imagine this would be useful in making this whole process easier but I am still not sure how to go about implementing all of this. Any help would be very much apprieciated!

Comment: use [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: I tried making a bunch of variables with each value but I think I am going to need to use yeah arrays for this. Even with arrays though I am not how to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put each each number with it's corresponding value into an array making number as key and value pair like this.

```
<?php
$arr = array(
  2=>  19,
  4=>  19,
  6=>  19,
  8=>  21,
  10=> 21,
  12=> 22,
  14=> 23,
  16=> 23,
  18=> 23,
  20=> 33,
  22=> 37,
  24=> 42,
  26=> 45,
  28=> 48,
  30=> 50,
  32=> 55,
  34=> 61,
  36=> 66,
  38=> 72,
  40=> 78,
  42=> 155,
  44=> 179,
  46=> 202,
  48=> 233,
  50=> 360,
);
?>
```

Loop array with foreach loop like this

```
<?php
$sum = 0;
foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
   if($k >= 16 && $k <= 38) 
      $sum += $v;
}
?>
```

There is another way using for loop statement, put both number in two separate array ($n and $v). Iterate the loop of the first array($n) and find the value from second array($v) through the index number of first array. But both array count should have same.
**Example-**

```
<?php
$n = array(2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20);
$v = array(19,19,19,21,21,22,23,23,23,33);
$sum = 0;
for($i=0, $i<count($n); $i++) {
   if($n[$i] >= 16 && $n[$i] <= 38)
      $sum += $v[$i];
}
?>
```

Comment: i think it should be `if($k >= 16 && $k <= 38)`

Comment: I will try this and see how it goes. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You would put your number and value pairs into an key / value array.  So a shortened version of your test data would look like this:

```
$myDataStore = array(
    "2" => "19",
    "4" => "19",
    "6" => "19",
    "8" => "21",
    "10" => "21",
    "12" => "22",
    "14" => "23",
    "16" => "23",
    "18" => "23",
    "20" => "23"
);
```

Now you need a function to calculate your sum given a range as defined by starting and ending numbers.

```
function getRangeTotal($array, $startNumber, $endNumber){
    $total = 0;
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        if($key >= $startNumber && $key <= $endNumber){
            $total = $total + $value;
        }
    }
    return $total;
}
```

If you run the above function

```
getRangeTotal($myDataStore, 6, 12);
```

You'll get `83`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do this using [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
// first store you data to an array.
$kv = array(
2  => 19, 4  => 19, 6  => 19, 8  => 21,
10 => 21, 12 => 22, 14 => 23, 16 => 23,
18 => 23, 20 => 33, 22 => 37, 24 => 42,
26 => 45, 28 => 48, 30 => 50, 32 => 55,
34 => 61, 36 => 66, 38 => 72, 40 => 78,
42 => 155, 44 => 179, 46 => 202,48 => 233,
50 => 360
);

$start = 16;
$end = 32;
$sum = 0; //variable to keep sum
$n = 0; //variable to keep count
//loop through the array
foreach ($kv as $k => $v){
    if ($k >=$start && $k <= $end){ //if key is in your range
        $sum += $v; //add value to sum
        $n ++; // increment count
    }
}
$v = 11.218*pow(M_E,0.057*$n); //calculate the approximate values
echo "$sum\n$v\n";
```

Also refer to : [pow](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php) and [Predefined Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/math.constants.php)